# Regex performance issue - can anyone explain way this regex is slow

Tags: c#, regex, performance

I'm trying to implement the `String.Contains()` method with `regex`. I noticed that this pattern `@".\*foo.\*"` takes much longer then this `@"\A.\*foo.\*\Z"`.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: that will depend on the string that your are querying?

Comment: Why are you inventing rectangular wheel?

Comment: @Leri, that isn't a particularly constructive comment?

Comment: @Liam When you see OP doing something wrong and you comment, it's perfectly constructive. :)

Comment: @Leri, what would of been constructive would of been to explain what he's doing wrong, why he's doing it wrong and what he should do to do things right.

Comment: @Liam My comment is slight modification of idiom _reinventing a wheel_ that does not need much explanations. And, I think, people on SO are clever enough to understand that.

Comment: @Leri: The OP is not doing anything wrong because they are not trying to solve a problem the wrong way. It should be clear enough: "I'm trying to implement the `String.Contains` method with regex". Obviously they know about `String.Contains` and they want to do it with regex as part of some exercise. They are not reinventing anything, just playing around to increase their understanding of how things work. And you have to admit that it does have results, because it led to this question and the answers that it brings.

Comment: If they had said "I am trying to find if a string is contained within another string with regex" then I 'd be 100% with you about reinventing things.

Comment: @Jon `I am trying to find if a string is contained within another string with regex` < How it sounded to me. If it's _really_ just playing around with regex, I take my words back.

Comment: There's no need to use `.\*` or `\A.\*`. You can just match on the string `"foo"` and that should work, but either way, using Regex for this is highly error prone as you'd need to make sure to escape any special characters that appear in the search string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because without the anchor the regex engine has to make more tries to match before it can conclude that a match is impossible. Consider an example with the anchor:

```
Regex: \A.*foo.*\Z
Input: 123456789abcdef
```

The regular expression sees the start of input anchor and takes that into account. It now tries to match the first `.*` pattern, and since it's greedy it attempts to match all the input. Then it tries to match `foo` and fails, so it releases `f` from the `.*` match and attempts again. It fails again, releases `e` from the `.*` match, attempts again, fails, etc.

The end result is that the number of attempts taken until the whole expression fails to match is *linear* to the length of the input.

Now consider the non-anchored case:

```
Regex: .*foo.*
Input: 123456789abcdef
```

This time the regex engine attempts to match from the start of the string, as above (making a linear to the length of the string amount of attempts). But when that fails, *it begins the process again starting from the second character of the input*.

That is, it attempts to match the first `.*` successively with:

```
123456789abcdef
123456789abcde
123456789abcd
...
1
                  (empty string due to the * quantifier)
```

Up till now this is the same as with the anchored regex. But while the anchor would cause matching to fail at this point, the non-anchored regex continues to try with

```
23456789abcdef
23456789abcde
23456789abcd
...
2
                  (empty string due to the * quantifier)
```

As you see, this time the number of attempts taken until the whole expression fails to match is *quadratic* to the length of the input.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
Im using the patten @"(\A.*foo.*\Z)"
but still the performance is around 100 times slower then String.Contains
i tried to use the lazy quantifier @"(\A.*?foo.*\Z)" or make it a non-capturing group @"(?:\A.*foo.*\Z)"
but performance was not better
Is there anything else i can do ?

Answer (score 1):

\A and \Z means beginning and the end of the string. Therefore the regex is more limited and has less searching to do. For example if your text has newlines in it, the 2nd regex is way faster since it only searches the first new line where the 1st regex keeps searching